# Indicator function of an exponentially distributed random variable.

Tags: probability-distributions

If $X\sim\mathrm{Exp}(1)$ how do I have to interprete:
$$
Y = \textbf{1}_{[c,\infty)}(X)
$$
where $\textbf{1}$ is the indicator function. I realize that $Y$ is $0$ if $X < c$ and $1$ if $X >= c$. But how do I calculate the probability distribution of Y or even the expectation value ?

Comment: By definition, $$
\mathbb P(Y=1) = \mathbb P(X>c) = e^{-c}.
$$
From here is it trivial to compute the expectation.

Comment: ... providing that $c \ge 0$.  Otherwise $\mathbb P(Y=1) = \mathbb P(X>c)= \mathbb P(X\ge 0) =1$